# How to add custom autocomplete dropdowns with buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, search, autocomplete

I'm wanting to create a search component like how Github does theirs, with the buttons on the right like "In this repository" or "All GitHub". I already have search and everything is working dandy, but now I want to add in the custom buttons in the dropdown. Basically I want the user to either be able to A.) Search in the "documentation" area of the website, or B.) Search in a different spot.

I'm not even sure what to search for here if someone can point me into the right direction of how they might be doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, wrapp your results on a `<div id="resWrapper">`
then:

```
foreach (yourarrayofresults){
//append to the resWrapper your results with an "<a>"
}
```

if you share your code i can help you with a little more specific, and explained code